# ios Social Framework Duplicate Tweet issue

Tags: ios, twitter, social-framework

I'm using `Social Framework` in iOS  for Twitter integration

```
SLComposeViewController * composeVC  = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];

success = [composeVC setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"xxx"]];
SLComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler myBlock = ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result)
{

     if (result == SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled)
     {
     }
     else
     {
         [self shareApiCall:service];
      }

      [composeVC dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];
};
```

As we are tweeting the same thing, it gives success in code, but then duplicate popup show. Is there any way we can know that the posted tweet was a duplicate tweet (through code)?